# What is wrong with thiis code. I am trying to write a program of infix to postfix conversion in python

Tags: stack

infix to postfix conversion using python
I am using deque for creating stack

```
from collections import deque

class Infix_to_prefix:
    def __init__(self):
        self.container = deque()
        self.output = deque()

    def push(self,val):
        self.container.append(val)

    def pop(self):
        self.container.pop()

    def peek(self):
        return self.container[-1]

    def is_empty(self):
        if len(self.container)==0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    
    def is_operator(self, ch):
        if ch in "+-*/^":
            return True
        else:
            return False
        
    def is_operand(self,ch):
        if (ch>='A' and ch<='Z') or (ch>='a' and ch<='z'):
            return True
        else:
            False

    def ranking(self, top, ch):
        rank = {
            '+': 1,
            '-': 1,
            '*': 2,
            '/': 2,
            '^': 3
        }
        if rank[top]<rank[ch]:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def Conversion(self, exp):
        for ch in exp:
            if self.is_operand(ch):
                self.output.append(ch)
            elif self.is_operator(ch):
                while True:
                    if self.is_empty():
                        self.push(ch)
                    else:
                        top = self.peek()
                        if top == '(':
                            self.push(ch)
                            break
                        elif self.ranking(top, ch):
                            self.push(ch)
                            break
                        else:
                            cpop = self.pop()
                            self.output.append(cpop)
            elif ch == '(':
                self.push(ch)
            elif ch == ')':
                cpop = self.pop()
                while cpop!='(':
                    self.output.append(cpop)
                    cpop = self.pop()

        while not self.is_empty():
            cpop = self.pop()
            self.output.append(cpop)
        print(("").join(self.output))

exp = "a+b*(c^d-e)^(f+g*h)-i"
s = Infix_to_prefix()
s.Conversion(exp)
```

When I am running this code it just keep running.
Is there is another method or another program for solving infix to postfix.
point out what is wrong in this code.

Please ignore from this line
also tell me why stack flow always keeps telling me to add some more detail every time i atry to ask a question.

Comment: For one thing, the last line of `is_operand` is just `False`, but it should probably be `return False`.  It looks like execution is getting stuck in the `while True:` loop when `ch` is '+'.  Self is empty, so it pushes '+'.  Then in the next iteration through the `while True:` loop, it does the self.peek, and that returns '+'.  So both `ch` and `top` are '+' at that point.  The `if` condition isn't met.  The `elif` condition isn't met.  So we do the `else` block and pop the '+'.  Then at the next iteration, we're back where we started -- `ch` is still '+' and we're empty again.

Comment: Thank you @jason44107, missing return was just my typing mistake however thank for pointing it , and I corrected the while True: loop in my code and its working fine now. Thanks for help.